# Duplicate grantedAuthorities are removed in spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-security

I am writing a user management system with spring boot, angularjs, jpa, ... all the user's features will be assigned to `grantedauthorities` and will send back to angularjs to design the home page accordingly but even though I am assigning the authorities to `ArrayList` and not `HashSet`, still duplicate features are removed.

Size of `grantedauthorities` is 12 at the end of loop and everything is fine but when it return the response, duplicates are removed.

```java
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

   @Autowired
   private UserJpaRepository userJpaRepository;

   @Autowired
   private RoleFeaturesJpaRepository roleFeaturesJpaRepository;

   @Override
   @Transactional
   public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException  {

      User user = userJpaRepository.findByUsername(username);
      if (user == null) {
         throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                    "Opps! user not found with user-name: " + username);
      }

      return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
         user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
         getAuthorities(user)
      );
   }

   private Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(User user) {
         
      ArrayList<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
      Role role = user.getRoles();
      for (Features features : role.getFeatures()){
          RoleFeaturesPK roleFeaturesPK = new RoleFeaturesPK();
          roleFeaturesPK.setRoleId(role.getId());
          roleFeaturesPK.setFeatureId(features.getId());
          Optional<RoleFeatures> roleFeatures = roleFeaturesJpaRepository.findById(roleFeaturesPK);
          RoleFeatures features_entity = roleFeatures.get();
          grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(features.getName()));
          grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(features_entity.getReadOption()));
          grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(features_entity.getReadWriteOption()));

      }
      return grantedAuthorities;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Duplicated GrantedAuthorities are removed by Spring when creating the User with this instruction from the passed authorities collection in the constructor :

```
    this.authorities = Collections.unmodifiableSet(sortAuthorities(authorities));
```

sortAuthorities will sort the authorities based on this comparator and the result will not contain duplications :

```
        private static class AuthorityComparator implements Comparator<GrantedAuthority>,Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = SpringSecurityCoreVersion.SERIAL_VERSION_UID;

    public int compare(GrantedAuthority g1, GrantedAuthority g2) {
        // Neither should ever be null as each entry is checked before adding it to
        // the set.
        // If the authority is null, it is a custom authority and should precede
        // others.
        if (g2.getAuthority() == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (g1.getAuthority() == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        return g1.getAuthority().compareTo(g2.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

Comment: Golden Point, but I didn't get how and where to use it to sort the issue out?

Answer (score 0):

```
 method getAuthorities seems ok, it is getting removed on return line maybe

 
private Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(User user) 

  return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
     user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
      getAuthorities(user)
       
  );
```

Comment: how's it now? ;)

Comment: you mean User is not a type of Collection<GrantedAuthority> ?